# SIOCDELRT: No such process

Tags: ssh

I am very much new to this, overtaking from our IT guy that has left the department I work in!

Anyway, we have a 'fix' that was written for us for sorting out importing errors.

I have 6 computers to SSH into (RTP1-6)

One machine constantly errors with **SIOCDELRT: No such process** when trying to 'route del default'

After checking I could ping to it fine, I've just been to see a user on the computer and they did point out one thing... that a while back the icons disappeared from the desktop, and our IT guy managed to get them back, however, ever since they've had this pencil with a cross around it on the icon!

[XiO red cross](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E2TSp.jpg)

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why do you want to delete the default route? Anyway, without having any other information, there are tons of documents on the internet that mention this error. Have a look and pick one that matches your situation: https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffcm&q=SIOCDELRT%3A+No+such+process&ia=web. Or provide more information, such as the current routing table. About those crossed-out pencils - I have no idea what they mean. Have you tried an image search? Is there any indication they might be related to the error?

Comment: Thanks for the links, I shall look into this further.

The IT guy simply left me 3 lines of code to run which are:

route del default
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
route add -net default gw 192.168.0.1 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev eth0 metric 1

As stated no other users occur this error than the one computer.

I am sure the red cross is linked as XiO is the software they're trying to import from.